# Cloning and Running outdated Android App?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm working on the Udacity Android Basics which is pretty outdated. The problem is when I'm trying to download and run their code. [This is the project](https://github.com/udacity/Pokemon) I'm trying to clone. I've done this a few times and it's usually not too hard but this time for some reason it only has one build.gradle version. Any help or point in the right direction would be great.[image]

Comment: There's 2 build.gradle files, one in the main directory and one in the subdirectory.  I suggest you specify what problems you're actually seeing in detail.

Comment: Right now I get an error saying "Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.1.1." but my distributionURL is distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip Honestly this is just really confusing, I've been searching for what feels like a couple of hours and I have no idea what to do. Its never this hard I don't understand why this project is so different, I added a screenshot to my post. Don't know if that will help